# ModX add-on Gallery don't work (invisible error window)

Tags: gallery, add-on, modx-revolution

I installed the Gallery Add-On for ModX Revo (2.3.3-pl) today.
But I am not able to add a new Album. If I try it the "Add Album window" just stays and a second window (strangely invisible) opens up. 
It "displays" a 500 Internal Server error.

The Modx logs are empty.
Google didn't help either.
Also tried the add-on Cliche with the same results.

The site is running on a shared host from alfahosting.de. Memory size is set to 64M and the php Version is 5.6.6.

I double checked all folder and file permissions as a 500 is most likely triggered by wrong permissions. (Files 644, Folders 755)

I hope you guys can help me (and others with the same problem)

Comment: Any errors in apache/modx logs?

Comment: @Vasis no, both are empty.